# Stopwatch that works on background

Tags: android, stopwatch

Are there any sample stopwatch project ( or tutorial ) that stopwatch timer will be shown in **notificationbar** and will **keep working even if application closed** ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple countdown timer will work, and will persist through `onPause()` if you allow it to.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

Refer to [this source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) for more information. You can also update TextViews if you need to show the timer.

**Edit** for count up specifically, try `Chronometer`, which can be found at [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html). You can also find a demo of this in the [Samples APK](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html).